# How can I change one function value in a boolean-valued java Function?

Tags: java

I am having a list of integers, for which every elements gets mapped to a boolean value:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers = ...;
Function<Integer, Boolean> crazyFunction = new Function<Integer, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(Integer integer) {
            return false;
        }
    };;
```

Now, I'm iterating in a for-loop in which `crazyFunction` shall be updated each iteration. The update shall just modify one function value, i.e. I want to have something like (in pseudocode):

```
crazyFunction_tmp(x) := IF x==c THEN true ELSE crazyFunction(x)
crazyFunction := crazyFunction_tmp
```

for a fixed `c`.

What would be a good style to do this?

EDIT: Maybe it might be helpful to add some detail. I tried the following:

```
crazyFunction = new Function<Integer, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(Integer integer) {
            if(integer == c)
                return true;
            else return crazyFunction.apply(integer);
        }
    };
```

but (1) this does not compile since `crazyFunction` isn't (and shouldn't be) `final` and (2) this seems to be too complicated. Isn't there an easy way?

Comment: explain ... *in which `crazyFunction` gets updated every iteration*

Comment: crazyFunction = c->(c == 5); rsp. "crazyFunction = c->(c == FIXEDCVALUE);"

Comment: @kai but this generates a function which is `false` for all values except for the fixed one, doesn't it?

Comment: @kai is it better now?

Comment: a little but still. I do see that you try to chain the functions but i do not see where the default comes from. But in general what you do is assign the original to a new variable and then reasign the original;

Comment: if `integer != c`, this would create infinite recursion (if it compiled). It sounds like you have two functions, an `actualCrazyFunction` and a `possiblyCallActualCrazyFunction`. Maybe split them up like that? Also, `Function<Foo, Boolean>` is probably better as `Predicate<Foo>`.

Comment: it won't if done correctly. you do that all the time if you want to chain a handler. but a little clue is missing to give an actual code(where does the default come from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you actually want is to use a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)?

```java
Predicate<Integer> crazyFunction = x -> false;
for (Integer thisInteger : listOfIntegers) {
    crazyFunction = crazyFunction.or(Predicate.isEqual(thisInteger));
}

// Is a given integer one of our integers?
boolean isGoodInteger = crazyFunction.apply(42);
```

Comment: Yes, this would suffice for this example. But is there a similar solution for any function?

Comment: If it's a `Predicate`, you can do `crazyFunction.or(x -> /* arbitrary expression */)`. I'm not sure what you mean by "any function"? If you want to create a stack of closures, where each closes over another, you will need to use a separate stack frame for each closure, so you need a function call somewhere in there.