# Given a java Function, how can I update one function value?

Tags: java, functional-programming

If I have a function `f` in OCaml, I can just type

```ocaml
let f x = if x=1 then 42 else f x
```

If this would not hide the old definition of `f`, this would be exactly what I would want. Now I'm looking for an equivalent in Java, but with the additional constraint that the reference in `Function f` *is* updated. I can create a `Function`-object

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f = new Function<>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer integer) {
        return integer+1;
    }
};;
```

And now could define a new `Function` via

```
Function<Integer, Integer> g = new Function<>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer integer) {
        if (integer==1)
            return 42;
        else
            return f.apply(integer);
    }
};;
```

However, this only works if `f` is declared `final` or effectively `final`. Thus I can't change the reference via `f = g;`. What can I do?

**EDIT**: To clearify, I *have to* set `f` such that it references a `Function` which uses the old `Function f` as it was referenced before. The desired code will look something like this:

```
while(f.apply(i) != 0){
    //as above:
    g = ... //should use "the newest" f
    f = g; //should be used next iteration
    //then:
    .... //some other code
    i = ...;
}
```

Comment: Java is pass-by-value, meaning you literally cannot change your parameters.  You can return a value instead.

Comment: @markspace Parameters aren't involved in this question. This question is about accessing references outside the scope of the anonymous class. OP is declaring f and g, and inside g's `apply` he wants to call `f.apply`, which isn't possible without `f` being final.

Comment: @BackSlash References are values too, so I think my comment applies.  But Integer is immutable, so changing anything in his example is basically "no."  Maybe a better example is needed?

Comment: @markspace No integer is being changed here. No parameter is being changed. To rephrase the question: *I declared f and g as anonymous classes. I want to use f inside g, so I need to make f final, but I also want to change f at some point but I can't since it's final. How can I solve this?*

Comment: Not sure if it can be used for your usecase but when a variable needs to be changed from a lambda expression the variable could be wrapped into an [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html). Something like `AtomicReference<Function> functionHolder = new AtomicReference(f);` and when needed change the function holded by the atomic reference instead of changing the instance of the atomic reference variable

Comment: So the OP just needs to keep a second copy of the reference that is mutable? Is that all they need?

Comment: @markspace Not a copy, since he wants to change the original reference (the copy won't help here)

Comment: @bruderjakob17 One approach would be to declare f and g at the class level, that way both of them can stay non-final and you'll be able to use them inside anonymous classes *and* edit them as you need. But I don't really like this approach.

Comment: Can you rewrite `g` as it would be with the compiler error? That would probably clarify the question.

Comment: I am not sure if I completly understand what the OP wants to do but perhaps extending Function<Integer,Integer> and adding a f (Function<Integer,Integer> as an attribute of the extended class with setter and getter can solve the issue with variable access and being able to change the value of f)

Comment: You already asked this question a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715491/how-can-i-change-one-function-value-in-a-boolean-valued-java-function. Why duplicating?

Comment: @yegodm the other question featured a problem in which I had a Boolean-valued function. The answer is not applicable if I'm having an Integer-valued function

Comment: @ernest_k the compiler yields an error in the line `f=g;`

Comment: In your new edit above, which `f` does `g` use after each time `f` gets assigned?

Comment: @markspace the `f` which was assigned in the last iteration, I have added a comment.

Comment: So in other words, g is recursive?  It after several iterations calls a chain of all previous g(f) functions?

Comment: @markspace yes :)

Comment: You'll need to call `new` for that.  In Java we don't allocate new memory just for assignment.  Need a new `g` to hold the `f` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be using `List`s:

```
ArrayList<Function<Integer, Integer>> fList = new ArrayList<>();
fList.add(i -> i+1);
Function<Integer, Integer> g = new Function<>(){
    final Function<Integer, Integer> fPre = fList.get(fList.size()-1);
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer integer){
        if (integer == 1)
            return 42;
        else
            return fPre.apply(integer);
    }
}
fList.add(g);
```

And later using `f = fList.get(fList.size()-1)` whenever `f` is needed outside the definition.

The idea is that we store all the `f`s in a `List`, from oldest to newest.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can't do it like this. As you've said the variable used in functional interface must be final (or effectively final). What you can do is to wrap the references, with AtomicReference for example. Then you'll have something like this:

```
    final AtomicReference<Function<Integer, Integer>> ref = new AtomicReference<>();

    Function<Integer, Integer> f = new Function<>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer integer) {
            return integer+1;
        }
    };

    ref.set(f);

    Function<Integer, Integer> g = new Function<>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer integer) {
            if (integer==1)
                return 42;
            else
                return f.apply(integer);
        }
    };

    ref.set(g);
```

And the function would be available by ref.get()

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the OP will also need `return ref.get().apply(integer);` instead of `return f.apply(integer);`

Comment: yes. alternatively u could make it a real class instead of an anonymous class and declare f as field.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. When ref.set(g); has been called you'll end up with StackOverflowError on any number other than 1.

Comment: @BackSlash yes :) I'm sorry, but I didn't know how to formulate my question better.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of one variable in your local scope by nesting the first function in the second one. Unless you need the two variables (unlikely, and in which case using the atomic reference solution proposed by A.Bitner is applicable), this should work:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {

    //this can even be made a local variable of f.apply() 
    final Function<Integer, Integer> innerFunction = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer integer) {
            return integer + 1;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer integer) {
        if (integer == 1)
            return 42;
        else
            return innerFunction.apply(integer);
    }
};
```

And an equivalent lambda expression:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f = i -> {
    Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = e -> e + 1;
    return i == 1 ? 42 : f1.apply(i);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I completly understand what the OP wants to do but perhaps extending `Function<Integer,Integer>` and adding a f (`Function<Integer,Integer>` as an attribute of the extended class with setter and getter can solve the issue with variable access and being able to change the value of f)

Note: I used a public attribute instead of setter and getter ...

```
public class TestClass{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Function<Integer, Integer> f = new Function<Integer,Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Integer integer) {
                return integer+1;
            }
        };

        MyFunction g = new MyFunction();
        g.f = f;

        g.apply(1);
     }



     public static class MyFunction implements Function<Integer,Integer>{

         public Function<Integer,Integer> f;

         @Override
         public Integer apply(Integer integer){
             if (integer==1)
                return 42;
             else
               return f.apply(integer);
         }

     }
}
```